# Using useSelector from redux and useEffect from react, but the value doesn't change even if I renew the value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

There are two components, I expected them to have same effect！However, they are not! For the first code, I have a var *n*, and I increace the *n* using useSelector from redux, I can see the *n* is cahnged when the selector is working. But there are still display the unchanged *n* in the return, I also use useEffect, if n is changed, renew the component. But still not work. However, the second code is work. The second code I also use useSlector to return the *n*, and that is work. Why the first code dosen't work, even if I use useEffect???

***My Question***
In my first code, I kept updating ***n*** in useSeletor, I thought that the state of ***n*** changed, it would trigger useEffect() (useEffect subscribed to ***[n]***) to update the component, but it doesn't seem to be. Why is this happening, I have subscribed to ***n*** with useEffect, doesn't every change you make update the component?

//First code

```
const TotalCompleteItems = () => {
  let n = 0
  let [state, setState] = useState
  useSelector(state => {
    n=0
    state.todos.forEach(element => {
        (element.completed===true) && (n++);
        console.log(n)
    })
 })
 useEffect(() => { 
 },[n])

 return <h4 className='mt-3'>Total Complete Items: {n}</h4>;
};                                                                                       
export default TotalCompleteItems;
```

//Second code

```
const TotalCompleteItems = () => {                                                          
    let n = useSelector(state => {
    let num=0
    state.todos.forEach(element => {
        (element.completed===true) && num++;
    })
    return num
}
)

return <h4 className='mt-3'>Total Complete Items: { n }</h4> };                          
export default TotalCompleteItems;
```

Comment: It's not clear at all what you are really trying to ask? It sort of sounds like you are trying to ask something about `n`?

Comment: @DrewReese I renew the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **My Question** In my first code, I kept updating `n` in `useSeletor`, I
> thought that the state of `n` changed, it would trigger `useEffect()`
> (`useEffect` subscribed to `[n]`) to update the component, but it doesn't
> seem to be. Why is this happening, I have subscribed to `n` with
> `useEffect`, doesn't every change you make update the component?

This is a little bit of the tail wagging the dog. You are mutating `n`, but simply mutating `n` isn't enough to trigger the component to rerender and call the `useEffect` hook at the end of the render cycle to check if any dependencies updated. This also wouldn't work anyway because `n` is always redeclared at the start of the render cycle.

If you are just wanting to compute a total completed value then just use an array.reduce over the `todos` array and return a computed count.

```
const TotalCompleteItems = () => {                                                          
  const n = useSelector(state => {
    return state.todos.reduce(
      (total, todo) => total + Number(!!todo.completed),
      0
    );
  });

  return <h4 className='mt-3'>Total Complete Items: {n}</h4>;
};
```

or more simply use an array.filter over the `todos` array and return the length.

```
const TotalCompleteItems = () => {                                                          
  const n = useSelector(state => {
    return state.todos.filter(todo => todo.completed).length;
  });

  return <h4 className='mt-3'>Total Complete Items: {n}</h4>;
};
```

Comment: Oh, nice! That means n is a variable, even if it changes, but the address of n is not change. Therefore, component will not renew by useEffect(). Is my understanding right?

Comment: @LeeAlex Affirmative, that is correct.